# freemarker iterating sequence of compound object

Tags: freemarker

I have a sequence coming from yaml data model like this:

```
project:
    artifactId: foo 
    groupId: org.foo
    profiles:
        - dev:
            baseurl: localhost
            baseport: 8080
        - uat:
            baseurl: foo.com
            baseport: 8443
        - prod:
            baseurl: foo.com
            baseport: 8444
```

in my template I can see that it is a sequence:

```
 <#if map.project.profiles?is_sequence>YES</#if>
```

I've tried to iterate like this:

```
 <#list map.project.profiles as n>           
    ${n?index} 
 </#list>
```

but how can I reach element baseurl? ${n?index} works well, but ${n.baseurl} or ${map.project.profiles[n].baseurl}  doesn't.
thx
Zamek

Answer (score 1):

It's the YAML that doesn't mean what you mean. When you have an item like this:

```
- dev:
    baseurl: localhost
    baseport: 8080
```

that creates an element in a list, but that element will be a `Map` that contains a singe entry, which entry has key `dev`, and a value that's another nested `Map`, which contains the keys `baseurl` and `baseport`. So, you had to write `n.dev.baseurl`, `n.prod.baseurl`, etc., but of course that would be a pain.

So, you want a YAML like this:

```
project:
    artifactId: foo 
    groupId: org.foo
    profiles:
        dev:
          baseurl: localhost
          baseport: 8080
        uat:
          baseurl: foo.com
          baseport: 8443
        prod:
          baseurl: foo.com
          baseport: 8444
```

or like this:

```
project:
    artifactId: foo 
    groupId: org.foo
    profiles:
        - server: dev
          baseurl: localhost
          baseport: 8080
        - server: uat
          baseurl: foo.com
          baseport: 8443
        - server: prod
          baseurl: foo.com
          baseport: 8444
```

Comment: thx a lot the second works well, the indentation is important.